# i want my balance keep updates when a purchase has been made

Tags: python, django

Hello i want create a virtual payment system.All the functions works properply but whenevr i purchase something my balance is not updating.

Here is my views.py :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ids = list(request.session.get('cart').keys())
        cart_products = Product.get_products_id(ids)
        product_prices = list(map(self.map_func, cart_products))
        total_due = sum(product_prices)

        balance = request.session['customer']['coin']

        if balance >= total_due:
            balance = balance - total_due
            Customer.objects.filter(id = request.session['customer']['id']).update(coin=balance)
            request.session['customer']['coin'] = balance

            return HttpResponse(balance)

        return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

Here is my index:

```
{% extends 'Home/header.html' %}
{% load cart %}
{% block content %}

{{user_orders.product.name}}
{{user_orders.product.price}}
{{total_due}}
<h5>{{request.session.customer.coin}}</h5>
<form action="" method="POST">

{% csrf_token %}

<input type="submit" name="payment_coin">
</form>





{% endblock %}
```

What i actually i want is when a purchased has been made account balance will be automaticly update.

Answer (score 1):

I believe update is used on querysets only. If I'm correct you only need to fetch one object at a time. See if this works.

Instead of this:

```
Customer.objects.filter(id = request.session['customer']['id']).update(coin=balance)
```

Try this:

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(id = request.session['customer']['id'])
customer.coin = balance
customer.save()
```

Comment: Does it throw an error? If so, can you post it?